# jQuery trigger for hidden buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have iframe and inside that frame I have a submit button and my iframe is inside a div. Sometime the div may be hidden. At the time of `display:none`, trigger to the submit button is not working.

```
.trigger('click');
```

Comment: How do you select the button to call `.trigger()`? Please show more of your code.

Comment: @Jacob: Please post the **relevant** HTML and script and if possible in **addition** a jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could manually submit the form using something like

```
$('#yourForm').submit();
```

Comment: Johan, but in my submission page it will check if(isset($_POST['submitbutton']))

Comment: `code`form_123 = document.getElementById(form_id[0]).contentWindow.document.forms[0]; var node_list = document.getElementById(form_id[0]).contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName(‌​'input'); for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) { var node = node_list[i]; if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'submit') { button_value = node.getAttribute('value').toLowerCase(); if(button_value.search('save') >= 0 || button_value.search('submit') >= 0){ $(node).trigger('click');document.getElementById(form_id[0]).contentWind‌​ow.document.forms[0].submit(); } } }`code`

Answer (score 1):

This works whether or not the div containing the iframe is hidden.

```
$('iframe').contents().find('input[type=submit]').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(document).delegate("Id or class here", "click", function () {

});
```

to define your event and then triggering the click on the class or id of the button.  The id or class require either # or . before them respectively.

```
$('#mybutton').trigger('click');
```

should trigger your click

Comment: $("#mybutton").trigger('click'); should work, do you have a code sample?

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jleslie/dbGY8/1/